# Rename metrics in Dropwizard MetricsRegistry in a Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, metrics, dropwizard

in my Spring Boot application, I am using a metrics library which is a wrapper over: `io.dropwizard.metrics`. So I am getting all the API and system metrics from `MetricsRegistry`.

As a result, while I am hitting the `/metrics` actuator endpoint, I am able to see all these metrics.

Now, the problem is: all the metric names in the format `a.b.c`, which I would like to rename as: `a_b_c`.

But I could not find any way to achieve the same.

Could anyone please help with a few pointers? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code de [`MetricRegistry.java`](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/blob/release/4.2.x/metrics-core/src/main/java/com/codahale/metrics/MetricRegistry.java), in theory you could iterate over the existing metrics in the `MetricsRegistry` and, for each metric, remove the metric from the registry and re-add it with the new name.

However, note that directly manipulating the `MetricsRegistry` like this might introduce issues or limitations, especially with metrics that are automatically managed or updated by other components within your application.

```java
import com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Component
public class MetricRenamer {

    @Autowired
    private MetricRegistry metricRegistry;

    @PostConstruct
    public void renameMetrics() {
        // Temporary map to hold the new metrics
        Map<String, Metric> renamedMetrics = new HashMap<>();

        metricRegistry.getMetrics().forEach((name, metric) -> {
            // Generate the new name
            String newName = name.replace('.', '_');
            
            // Add to the temporary map
            renamedMetrics.put(newName, metric);
        });

        // Remove the old metrics and add the renamed ones
        renamedMetrics.forEach((newName, metric) -> {
            metricRegistry.remove(newName.replace('_', '.'));
            metricRegistry.register(newName, metric);
        });
    }
}
```

Before renaming, consider keeping a backup of original metric names and their references, for making sure you can revert changes if needed.
If your application updates metrics in a highly concurrent environment, consider the implications of modifying the `MetricsRegistry` at runtime. You may need to implement additional synchronization or use a [`MetricRegistryListener`](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/blob/release/4.2.x/metrics-core/src/main/java/com/codahale/metrics/MetricRegistryListener.java) to manage changes dynamically.

Again, directly manipulating the `MetricsRegistry` might not be suitable for all applications, especially those that rely on automatic metric registration and updates.

---

> manipulating the MetricsRegistry might not be suitable for all applications, especially those that rely on automatic metric registration and updates, what do you suggest in such a scenario for changing the names of the metrics?

You could try indeed to extend `MetricRegistry` and override the method responsible for registering metrics. That custom registry can then replace the default one in your Spring Boot application context.

```java
import com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry;
import com.codahale.metrics.Metric;

public class CustomMetricRegistry extends MetricRegistry {
    @Override
    public <T extends Metric> T register(String name, T metric) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        // Modify the metric name here before it is registered
        String modifiedName = name.replace('.', '_');
        return super.register(modifiedName, metric);
    }
}
```

To use your custom registry, you need to make sure it is the one picked up by Spring Boot's autoconfiguration. That often involves defining it as a bean before the default configuration kicks in:

```java
@Configuration
public class MetricsConfig {

    @Bean
    public MetricRegistry metricRegistry() {
        return new CustomMetricRegistry();
    }
}
```

---

If you are dealing with a more complex scenario where metrics are being registered through a `MetricSet` or via a `MetricBuilder`, consider wrapping these constructs to modify metric names at the point of creation.

```java
import com.codahale.metrics.*;

public class CustomMetricSet implements MetricSet {
    private final MetricSet original;

    public CustomMetricSet(MetricSet original) {
        this.original = original;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Metric> getMetrics() {
        // Transform metric names in the original set
        return original.getMetrics().entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                entry -> entry.getKey().replace('.', '_'),
                Map.Entry::getValue
            ));
    }
}
```

Then, when you register your `MetricSet`:

```java
metricRegistry.registerAll(new CustomMetricSet(yourOriginalMetricSet));
```

---

> My one doubt here is: where should I register the custom metric set. Should I do it on ApplicationReadyEvent?

Yes, registering your custom metric set [on the `ApplicationReadyEvent`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html) should work in a Spring Boot application: it makes sure your custom metric set is registered after all the autoconfiguration is complete but before the application starts serving traffic: your metrics are in place and ready to be used as soon as your application is up.

```java
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry;

@Component
public class CustomMetricSetRegistrar implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private MetricRegistry metricRegistry;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        // Assuming you have an existing MetricSet that you wish to wrap
        MetricSet yourOriginalMetricSet = ...; // Your existing MetricSet

        // Wrap and register the MetricSet with transformed metric names
        metricRegistry.registerAll(new CustomMetricSet(yourOriginalMetricSet));
    }
}
```

`CustomMetricSet` is a wrapper around your original `MetricSet` that you have designed to modify the metric names according to your naming convention (e.g., replacing dots with underscores). When the application is fully ready, this listener triggers, wrapping and registering your metric set with the modified names.

---

> This is working fine for system metrics emitting from Scone-based applications like JVM, GC metrics, etc.
>
> However, one issue I am facing is as follows: I have registered a few API metrics by extending `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`, but I cannot find any of the API metrics in `CustomMetricRegistry`.

If you have extended `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` to register API metrics and they are not appearing in your `CustomMetricRegistry`, check if:

- the API metrics registration is happening before your custom metric registry is fully set up or recognized by the application context.
  Make sure your custom metric registry is declared and initialized early. Using a `@Bean` method in a `@Configuration` class, as shown in your setup, is usually sufficient. Consider marking the configuration class with `@Priority` or using `@DependsOn` if there are specific beans that must be initialized first (see "[`@Order` in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-order)").
- your interceptor is referencing a different instance of `MetricRegistry` than the one you have customized and registered as a bean. That can happen in a Spring Boot application due to the way beans are auto-configured and instantiated.
  In your `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` implementation, explicitly autowire your custom metric registry to make sure it is using the correct instance. For example:

  ```java
  @Autowired
  private CustomMetricRegistry metricRegistry;
  ```

  If your custom registry extends `MetricRegistry`, make sure you are injecting the right type. If necessary, qualify the autowiring with `@Qualifier` to make sure the correct bean is used.
- your custom metric registry is getting overridden or not used where you expect (if there are multiple beans of type `MetricRegistry` or if auto-configuration creates a default one).
  Use Spring Boot's actuator endpoint `/beans` or the [Spring Boot Admin](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-admin) interface to inspect the beans in your application context. Look for multiple instances of `MetricRegistry` and see which one is being injected into your interceptor. You might need to use `@Primary` on your custom metric registry bean to make sure it is the one being picked up by default.

If API metrics are still not showing up, consider registering them explicitly after your application is fully started, similar to how you handled system metrics with the `ApplicationReadyEvent`. That makes sure the registration happens after all configurations and auto-configurations are complete.

```java
@Component
public class ApiMetricsRegistrar implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private CustomMetricRegistry metricRegistry;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        // Register your API metrics here to use the custom metric registry
    }
}
```

That way, your API metrics are registered with the correct `MetricRegistry` instance and at the right time in the application lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks, @Vonc for your answer. As you mentioned,  manipulating the MetricsRegistry might not be suitable for all applications, especially those that rely on automatic metric registration and updates, what do you suggest in such a scenario for changing the names of the metrics? 

I thought about overriding the method that is responsible for ingesting the metrics in the registry, but I did not find any such method. Then I would not have to manipulate the registry.

Comment: Thanks @Vonc. I think, this solution would address all the corner cases, as you mentioned earlier. My one doubt here is: where should I register the my custom metric set. Should I do it  on ApplicationReadyEvent ?

Comment: @Joy Yes, that should work. I have edited the answer to illustrate that approach.

Comment: This is working fine for system metrics emitting from Scone-based applications like JVM, GC metrics, etc.

However, one issue I am facing is as follows: I have registered a few API metrics by extending HandlerInterceptorAdapter, but I cannot find any of the API metrics in CustomMetricRegistry.